# when using functions on PostgreSQL partitoned tables it does a full table scan

Tags: sql, enterprisedb

The tables are partitioned in a PostgreSQL 9 database.  When I run the following script:

```
select * from node_channel_summary
where report_date between '2012-11-01' AND '2012-11-02';
```

it send the data from the proper tables without doing a full table scan.  Yet if I run this script:

```
select * from node_channel_summary
where report_date between trunc(sysdate)-30 AND trunc(sysdate)-29;
```

in this case it does a full table scan which performance is unacceptable.  The -30 and -29 will be replaced by parameters.

After doing some research, Postgres doesn't work properly with functions and partitioned tables.

Does somebody know as a work around to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you using table inheritance to achieve partitioning?

Comment: What are `trunc()` and `sysdate`?  They are certainly not PostgreSQL things...

Comment: I assumed we're actually talking about [EnterpriseDB](http://enterprisedb.com/solutions/oracle-compatibility-technology): fundamentally PostgreSQL, but supporting myriad Oracle features, including [`trunc()` and `sysdate`](http://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.1/oracompat/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_Oracle_Compatibility_Guide-72.htm#P5531_309120).

Comment: Proper tagging requires that you include only enterprisedb then, and not postgresql, so as not to confuse people as apparently has been done. Is there a reason I can't remove that tag? (aka I'm going to have done so, restore it ___and___ leave a comment if you must revert it)

Comment: I am new to the PostgreSQL world. I am using the EntrepriseDB running SQL scripts from pgAdmin III.  The function `trunc()` and `sysdate` are used in my SQL scripts and works as expected.  Unless you have a better way of getting today's date in postgreSQL.

Comment: The idiomatic way of getting today's date in PostgreSQL is `now()::date`. `trunc(sysdate)` is very Oracle.

Comment: @willglynn personally I use `CURRENT_DATE` for readability's sake.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that PostgreSQL calculates and caches execution plans when you compile the function. This is a problem for partitioned tables because PostgreSQL uses the query planner to eliminate partitions. You can get around this by specifying your query as a string, forcing PostgreSQL to re-parse and re-plan your query at run time:

```
FOR row IN EXECUTE 'select * from node_channel_summary where report_date between trunc(sysdate)-30 AND trunc(sysdate)-29' LOOP
    -- ...
END LOOP;

-- or
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select * from ...'
```